# Change point coordinates

Tags: arrays, c, function, structure, point

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

We have one point in the function `main`, which represents the center of the coordinate system with a certain name `O(0,0)`, how to use the function `function` to change that point in `A(1,2)`?

Here's my code:

```
struct Point {char m;float x, y;};
void function(struct Point t, char s,float array[2])
{
   t.m=s;
   t.x=array[0];
   t.y=array[1];

}
int main()
{
   float array[]={1,2};
   struct Point t1={'O',0,0};;
   function(t1,'A',array);
   printf("%c(%.2f,%.2f)",t1.m,t1.x,t1.y);
   return 0;
}
```

Note the function `function` must have a prototype `function(struct Point t,char s,float array[2]);`

Thanks in advance!

Best regards!

Comment: If you cannot change the function prototype then you cannot do this. You need to either pass a pointer to `Point` or return a `Point` object

Comment: I succeeded through the pointer, it was a problem for me that I could not understand without the pointer. Thank you !

Comment: just for the record, you actually changed the prototype by sending a pointer instead of a copy of the object

Comment: So, *"the function function must have a prototype `function(struct Point t,char s,float array[2]);`"* is actually false?

Comment: As a side note, the last parameter would be less confusing either as `float *array` (same as what it is now!), or `float array[static 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. The provided function prototype provides no way to return any modified values to its callers other than floats.

Comment: I succeeded through the pointer, it was a problem for me that I could not understand without the pointer. Thank you !

Comment: @LogicnotFound Through *what* pointer? The required prototype only has pointers to `float`s.